# Generating Java proxy class from wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, wsdl2java

I started working with web services and i want to create a web service java client. I tried to generate code from wsdl using idea tool but this errror messeages occurs. I would really appreciate some help because I am new to web services.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.DefaultAuthenticator$1 (file:/C:/Users/psadura/IdeaProjects/Klient/lib/jaxws-tools.jar) to field java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.DefaultAuthenticator$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
parsing WSDL...


[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q1:ArrayOfstring' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 1 of https://datastore.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG.DataStore/services/DataStoreProvider201901.svc?singleWsdl#types?schema1

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:461)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BindInfo.getJAXBContext(BindInfo.java:335)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.apply(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:235)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:541)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2244)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:137)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:391)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:204)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:135)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 28 more
Done
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource` Can You add `javax.activation` to Your build?

Answer (score 0):

Its shows `ClassNotFoundException` which means the class which you are calling is not present i.e. `javax/activation/DataSource`